# How to fill and output an array from right to left ussing input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

I have an input in which the user enters a number and that number appears in the box below. The user can enter a maximum of 4 numbers. Every time when user enters a number it mapped with array. I try to make so that at first in an array there were only empty fields and when the user enters numbers they appeared not from left to right and from right to left and replaced empty fields. I tryed different variants but they didn't work;
Value is come from another component and at once appear in layout.

```
Scenario:
Step 1
I have _ _ _ _
Step 2 I write number '8'
I have _ _ _ 8
Step 3 I write number '9'
I have _ _ 8 9
```

```
<input type='text' value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />
  <div>
    {Array(4)
      .fill('')
      .map((it, i) => (
         <span key={i}>{value[i]}</span>
       ))}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your use case but you are traversing array in same order so this is printing in same order just inverse the traversing you would get desired result.

```
<input type='text' value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />
<div> {Array(4)
  .fill('')
  .map((it, i) => (
     <span key={i}>{value[value.length - i - 1]}</span>
   ))}
</div>
```

Edit 1 -

```
<div>
    {Array(4)
      .fill("")
      .map((it, i) => {
        return i < 4 - value.length && <span key={i}>_</span>;
      })}
    <span>{value}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use this it will print _ unless there is any number less than length 4 in input and then add the number.

Comment: I edit my desription. your variant add reverse numbers, but thank you

Comment: That's simple add conditional span, wait adding the code.